# HQL - check if string can be converted to number

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to write HQL which will check if string/varchar can be converted to number and if yes it should be converted, if no null should be returned. I need to do it because this converted number will be used to calculate some data. It should look like this:

```
... CASE WHEN can_be_converted_to_number(p.someString) THEN CAST(p.someString as NUMBER) ELSE NULL END as someNumber
```

How can i do it using hql?

Comment: What about using a regex with rlike?

Answer (score 1):

It replace all non-decimal characters and try to cast to integer.  It is pl/pgSql function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_number(text varchar) RETURNS int AS $BODY$
    BEGIN   
        text := regexp_replace(text, '[^0-9]+','');
        RETURN CAST(text as int);
        EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

If you want use this function in HQL, you must extend your Dialect and register this function. E.g.:

```
public class CustomPostgresSqlDialect extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {

    public CustomPostgresSqlDialect(){
        super();
        registerFunction("extract_number", new ExtractNumberFunction());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is very Postgres dependant

Comment: Yes, but in the other RDBMS it should be very similar, if not same.